# Why is my stringstream empty?

Tags: c++, string, stream

This is what the piece of code below is supposed to do. It's supposed to read the info in the stream (called lineStream) that has been inputted by the user into an int. The data is either supposed to be a single number or the word "all". If it's neither I'm supposed to inform the user it's an error.

This is what happens though: when the user enters a number everything works out fine. When he enters the word "all" though, the stream fails (as expected since I'm reading it into an int). When this happens I try reading the info in the stream into a string ("stringstream") and checking if the user has entered "all". However, even when the user has entered "all", the stream only outputs "" (empty string) when I try to read from it after it fails. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

```
int nameofnode;

lineStream >> nameofnode;

if (lineStream.fail())
{ 
    string streamString;
    lineStream >> streamString;

    if (streamString == "all") {

        if (lineStream.peek() != EOF) { //Too many arguments
            cout << "Error: too many arguments\n";
            return;
        }

        cout << "Print: all nodes\n";
    }
   else
    {
        cout << "Error: Invalid argument";
    }

   return;
}
```

Comment: The stream is still in a fail-state, which you never cleared before retrying your extraction by-string rather than by-int.

Comment: @WhozCraig If the stream is in a fail state, does that mean I can't read from it? I thought it only mean't I can't use any of its functions.

Comment: Until the fail-state is cleared, you can't do much of *anything* with a iostream. And what do you think "read from it" does, if not "use any of its functions."? The extraction `operator >>` is just a front end for pulling formatted data out of the stream using stream-members. Pretty sure you're looking for invoking the [**clear()**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) method prior to your string-try.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you, that fixed it. Post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once in a fail-state, there is next-to-nothing you can do with an iostream without clearing the fail state one way or another. In this case..

```
int nameofnode;

if (!(lineStream >> nameofnode))
{ 
    lineStream.clear(); // <<==== HERE

    string streamString;
    if (lineStream >> streamString && streamString == "all") {

        if (lineStream.peek() != EOF) { //Too many arguments
            cout << "Error: too many arguments\n";
            return;
        }

        cout << "Print: all nodes\n";
    }
   else
    {
        cout << "Error: Invalid argument";
    }

   return;
}
```